# Berry naming scheme list of LaTeX font families

Tags: fonts, documentation, berry

Could you provide me with a list of Berry names for LaTeX font families?

I am currently working on a paper comparing various LaTeX fonts, particularly their support of extended Latin and it took some time to figure out these obsolete three-letter codes for the TeX Gyre families (to change font families using `\fontfamily{nnn}\selectfont`). Rather than gathering all the `.map` files, I tried to look them up on the Internet, but with no success.

The documentation of the [PSNFSS bundle](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/psnfss) features the following packages: `times`, `palatino`, `helvet`, `avant`, `newcent`, `bookman`, `courier`, `pifont`, `chancery`, `mathptm`, `mathpple`, `charter`, `utopia`, `mathpazo`. It is possible to extract the codes, but it is unnecessarily time-consuming and some are still missing (such as TeX Gyre).

Should someone look for the same, here are the Berry names of TeX Gyre families:

- Adventor – `qag`
- Bonum – `qbk`
- Chorus – `qzc`
- Cursor – `qcr`
- Heros – `qhv`
- Pagella – `qpl`
- Schola – `qcs`
- Termes – `qtm`

Comment: you can look into the package, e.g. `tgpagella.sty` for the font name. Or use `XeTeX` or `LuaTeX` then you can use the official font name.

Comment: Some are listed at http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/25251/4012

Comment: The file http://www.tug.org/fontname/fontname.pdf contains a large listing.

Comment: Related question: [fonts - Quickest way to search for valid \fontfamily arguments? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/118969/quickest-way-to-search-for-valid-fontfamily-arguments)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The names can be found in `fontname.pdf` (`texdoc fontname` on TeX Live systems); on page 4 there is the list of "suppliers" and GUST Typefoundry appears as `q`. Since TeX Gyre Termes, for instance, is a clone of Times, its family name is `qtm`.

- `ag` Avant Garde
- `bk` Bookman
- `zc` Zapf Chancery
- `cr` Courier
- `hv` Helvetica
- `pl` Palatino
- `cs` Century Schoolbook (the Adobe one is NewCentury Schoolbook, `pnc`)
- `tm` Times

There are listings by supplier in the appendix, but GUST Typefoundry doesn't (still) appear.

Comment: the list is incomplete, it doesn't show all that fonts which start with x, e.g. libertine

Comment: @Herbert On my copy `xl` appears at the end of page 16; the font supplier is `f` (small foundry), so `fxl` is the family name; on the other hand Biolinum is not listed.

Comment: @egreg Does Biolinum *have* a Berry name?

Comment: @cfr It used to have one, now it doesn't. The family name is one among `*-LF`, `*-TLF`, `*-OsF` or `*-TOsF`, where `*` is `LinuxBiolinumT`

Comment: @egreg Thanks. That makes sense. I seemed to think it did but when I looked, it was using what I think of as the autoinst names so I was puzzled.

Answer (score 0):

Anselm Lingnau gives a little (incomplete) reference in his book "LaTeX Hacks". See page 236 (hack no. 67):

> Computer Modern Roman: cmr
>
> Adobe Times Roman: ptr
>
> Adobe Palatino: ppt
>
> ITC Bookman: pbk
>
> Adobe New Century Schoolbok: pnc
>
> Bera Serif: fve
>
> URW Classico ("Optima"): uop
>
> Computer Modern Sans: cmss
>
> Computer Modern Bright: cmbr
>
> Adobe Helvetica: phv
>
> ITC Avant Garde Gothic: pag
>
> Bera Sans: fvs
>
> Computer Modern Typewriter: cmtt
>
> Adobe Courier: pcr

(I left out those who are not free ware.)