# What is the font family name for Cabin?

Tags: fonts

I need to set cabin font locally in my document. what is font family for cabin font?

```
{
   \fontfamily{x}\selectfont
    Some text in anttlc...
}
```

x = ?

Regards

Comment: I suppose that there is no LaTeX support for that font. Use `xelatex` or `lualatex` instead.

Comment: I cannot use xelatex and lualatex.

Comment: then you have to create the LaTeX support files which isn't really easy.

Answer (score 15):

According to [the LaTeX font catalogue](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/cabin/), there is a package providing the Cabin font.
According to the package, the font family is `Cabin-TLF`:

```
\fontfamily{Cabin-TLF}\selectfont
```

Of course it much easier to just load the package:

```
\usepackage[sfdefault]{cabin}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
```

Also see:

- [How do I use a particular font for a small section of text in my document?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25249/how-do-i-use-a-particular-font-for-a-small-section-of-text-in-my-document)
- [Berry naming scheme list of LaTeX font families](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23592/berry-naming-scheme-list-of-latex-font-families)

Comment: answering questions by reading documentation? it'll never catch on (+1) :-)

Comment: cabin.sty not found

Comment: @user15662: Cabin was added quite recently. Make sure your TeX distribution is up-to-date.

Comment: @David: Not to derail totally here, but many package documentations are virtually incomprehensible to novice users. Just the other day I was trying to figure out how to use ``lineno`` by reading the documentation, and I understood next to nothing. A common experience for me.

Comment: @Sverre I'm sure that's true of my packages:-)

Comment: @David: Yes and no. I found the answer to something in your ``longtable`` documentation today, so I understood some of that. The documentation for ``ltxtable``, on the other hand, could be a tad more elaborate ... :)

Answer (score 6):

On a Unix system (assuming a Bash shell) one can issue the following command to a terminal:

```
ls $(dirname $(kpsewhich cabin.sty))
```

which, on a recently updated TeX Live, will output

```
LY1Cabin-TLF.fd           OT1CabinCondensed-TLF.fd  TS1Cabin-TLF.fd
LY1CabinCondensed-TLF.fd  T1Cabin-TLF.fd            TS1CabinCondensed-TLF.fd
OT1Cabin-TLF.fd           T1CabinCondensed-TLF.fd   cabin.sty
```

Since `.fd` files are named after the family name, you get what you need by stripping off the encoding name (which actually should be lowercased, according to the guidelines) and the `.fd`, getting

```
Cabin-TLF
```

for the normal font or

```
CabinCondensed-TLF
```

for the condensed variant.

On other systems lacking a shell (or where it's difficult to use), just do a search for `cabin.sty` in the file system.

Comment: I m working on Red Hat. How to search there?

Comment: @user15662 The procedure with the terminal should work on Red Hat.

Comment: But i got following error message. ls $(dirname $(kpsewhich cabin.sty))
dirname: missing operand
Try `dirname --help' for more information.

Comment: @user15662 Are you using a Bash shell? That seems to point to a different shell.

Comment: NO i am running on my redhat terminal in my home folder.

Answer (score 4):

<strike>As Herbert said, there is no pdfTeX support for that font yet.</strike> Okay, so there *is* pdfTeX support for Cabin :) Maybe the rest of my answer is going to be useful for people in need of support files for other fonts, as it applies to every (OpenType) font you want to use in pdfTeX.

That support is required because traditional pdfTeX doesn't natively support the font formats common these days. If you can't or don't want to use a more contemporary TeX engine, you can use [`otftotfm`](http://www.lcdf.org/type/index.html) and [`autoinst`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/utilities/fontools) to (a) convert an OpenType font to a PostScript font that pdfTeX can use and (b) create the required support files. That should be the most comfortable way. Both tools come with a useful documentation. Once you have them installed, all it should take is a line that looks something like this:

```
perl autoinst.pl --fractions --inferiors --superiors --verbose --noswash --noornaments --smallcaps --sanserif --extra="--force" MyriadPro-Regular.otf ...
```

...plus some cleaning up afterwards and moving files to the right places. I'd say about an afternoon if it's your first time using it, and a couple of minutes for every subsequent font, once you've got that procedure internalized.