# Insert fonts in Latex

Tags: fonts

I found this command that allows you to insert an Adobe font like Helvetica

`\renewcommand{\stitlefont}{\fontfamily{phv}\fontsize{14pt}{14pt}\selectfont}`

I have more questions:

1. *phv* is an abbreviation? Are there others?
2. Similarly I can insert font ttf? Just change the name between braces, like **{berasans}**?

Thanks!

Comment: Related to 1: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23592/berry-naming-scheme-list-of-latex-font-families

Comment: If you want to use system fonts XeTeX or LuaTeX's `fontspec` might be worth a look. http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/226/installing-ttf-fonts-in-latex

Comment: The document http://www.tug.org/fontname/fontname.pdf has many of these abbreviations

Comment: I've duped against one of the questions here: it's a multi-part, so the other part has to 'dangle'.