# How to find the 'font code' of adobe-utopia?

Tags: fonts, pdftex, mathdesign, fontfamily

I'd like to change some paragraph or part of my text to have the font `adobe utopia` from [here](https://tug.org/FontCatalogue/utopia-mathdesign/). It works if I set the whole document default to this font. But I would only need to use it like

```
{\fontfamily{ugq}\selectfont This needs to be ingrotesk.}
```

to change some paragraph. My question now is, how do I find the font-code (`ugq` in the example)?

I found [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/202789/where-to-find-the-family-code-for-a-custom-font), which I tried to follow, but I there's no `adobe-utopia.fd` file on my system.

Does anyone know how to determine this font-code?

Thanks.

Comment: `\fontfamily{put}`, if I remember well. But you might also use `erewhon` which is a clone with more features (bold smallcaps, superior and inferior figures, &c.)

Comment: If you look in `utopia.sty`, you can find `\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{put}`. You can also find it tracing through `mathdesign`, but it is more complicated.